# use mongodb inside aws lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda

I have created a lambda function using nodeJs. i have configured it to run inside my VPC where my mongo EC2 instance is running and the lambda is connected to Kinesis stream. first i worked with DynamoDB but regarding query capabilities and overall prices, I have decided to use mongo. When my function get trigger I am getting invocation errors and I dont know the real source and reasons

the error I get:

```
    Unable to import module 'index': Error
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/bson/index.js:1:74)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb-     core/index.js:1:74)
   at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

my dependencies are

> 

```
"dependencies": {
>             "bluebird": "^3.4.7",
>             "lodash": "^4.17.2",
>             "moment": "^2.17.1",
>             "mongodb": "^2.2.21",
>             "request": "^2.79.0",
>             "request-promise": "^4.1.1"
>        }
```

Comment: This might help http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html

Comment: how? it is general on lambda with S3, i get failure loading mongo modules

Answer (score 0):

My mistake - bad zip. it didnt include the lib folders